# store mongodb result in array?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Is it possible to store the result of a mongodb statement in array using **jquery**

I have like this

```
Polls_Coll.find({},{question:1});
```

I want all the question filed records to store in array some thing like

```
var arr[]=Polls_Coll.find({},{question:1});
```

I know above thing is wrong. I need something like that.

I need it for autocompletion. Now i'm taking source from one collection like this

```
 source:_(Product_Mobiles.find().fetch()).pluck("title")
```

I want data from multiple sources and store it in array

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the mongo console you can do this with .toArray() like

```
var results = db.collection.find({}).toArray();
```

However, this might depend on the driver you are using... I guess the javascript driver has it as well.

If your problem is putting all the results from multiple sources into a single array:
[How to merge two arrays in Javascript and de-duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: Get the results from each source and then concatenate the arrays into a single array.

Answer (score 2):

You could merge the two arrays if thats what you mean:

```
var results = collection.find({}).fetch();
var results2 = collection2.find({}).fetch();

results = results.concat(results2);
```

Then you can do `pluck`

```
_(results).pluck("title");
```

Also you can't use `db.` in Meteor you have to use the name of the collection varaible you defined with `new Meteor.Collection`